# Regex pattern with embedded double quotes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, escaping, quoting

Following keyword need to be searched on document using PowerShell:

```
["Allowed Acquisition Clean-Up Period"
```

```
$keyword = ""
Get-Content $SourceFileName | Select-String -Pattern $keyword
```

String which I'm searching for has double quotes in it, so I'm struggling how to mention in this `$keyword`.

Comment: Just a tip: You can use the `[regex]::Escape()` method if you're unsure about what to escape in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you not only have double quotes, but also an opening square bracket. Square brackets are meta-characters in regular expressions (for defining character classes), so you need to escape those too.

Define your expression in single quotes:

```
$keyword = '\["Allowed Acquisition Clean-Up Period"'
```

or escape nested double quotes with backticks:

```
$keyword = "\[`"Allowed Acquisition Clean-Up Period`""
```

Comment: above doesn't work with LIKE clause
$SearchKeyword1 =  '\["Lookup keyword"'
if ($para.Range.Text -Like $SearchKeyword1)

Comment: @user3657339 Of course it doesn't. Regular expression matches (`-match`, `Select-String`) and wildcard matches (`-like`) are **not** the same and do **not** use the same patterns.

Answer (score 3):

To *complement* [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51694866/45375), which contains the correct solution:

Given that `"` is not a regex metacharacter (has no special meaning in a regular expression), your question boils down to:
**How can I embed a `"` (double quote) in a string in PowerShell?**.

- As an aside: As stated, `[` *is* a regex metacharacter, so it must be escaped as `\[` inside a regex in order to be treated as a *literal*. As [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) points out, you can let [`[regex]::Escape($string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Escape_System_String_) handle that escaping for you; the result treats the content of `$string` *literally* in the context of a regex.

There are several options, demonstrated here with a simplified sample string, `3 " of rain` - see also: [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules):

```
# Inside a *literal string* ('...'):
# The content of single-quoted strings is treated *literally*.
# Double quotes can be embedded as-is.
'3 " of rain'

# Inside an *expandable string* ("..."):
# Such double-quoted strings are subject to *expansion* (interpolation)
# of embedded variable references ("$var") and expressions ("$(Get-Date)")
# Use `" inside double quotes; ` is PowerShell's escape character.
"3 `" of rain"                                                                                 #"
# Inside "...", "" works too.
"3 "" of rain"

# Inside a *literal here-string* (multiline; end delimiter MUST be 
# at the very beginning of a line):
# " can be embedded as-is.
@'
3 " of rain
'@

# Inside an *expanding here-string*:
# " can be embedded as-is, too.
@"
3 " of rain
"@
```

For the sake of completeness: you can **create a double quote via its Unicode code point** (the number that identifies each character), which is `0x22` (hex) / `34` (decimal), by casting it to `[char]`, e.g.: **`[char] 0x22`**.
You can use this:

- in **string concatenations**: `'3 ' + [char] 0x22 + ' of rain'`
- in **string-formatting expressions with the `-f` operator**: `'3 {0} of rain' -f [char] 0x22`